# PHP Warning: Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings

Tags: php, apache

I am getting following error whien i use php -i

> date
>
> date/time support => enabled "Olson" Timezone Database Version =>
>   0.system Timezone Database => internal PHP Warning:  Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.
>   You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezon
>   e_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are
>   still gettin
>   g this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected
>   'UTC' for 'UTC/0.0/no DST' instead in Unknown on line 0 Default
>   timezone => UTC
>
> Directive => Local Value => Master Value date.default_latitude =>
>   31.7667 => 31.7667 date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333 date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333 date.sunset_zenith =>
>   90.583333 => 90.583333 date.timezone => America/Los_Angeles => America/Los_Angeles

My /etc/php.ini has following setting

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone
date.timezone = America/Los_Angeles

; http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.default-latitude
;date.default_latitude = 31.7667

; http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.default-longitude
;date.default_longitude = 35.2333

; http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.sunrise-zenith
;date.sunrise_zenith = 90.583333

; http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.sunset-zenith
;date.sunset_zenith = 90.583333
```

PHP version details are as below

> PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Dec  5 2013 07:09:40) Copyright (c) 1997-2010
>   The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend
>   Technologies

Apache version as below

> Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) Server built:   Jul 18 2014
>   02:31:29

I have restarted Apache multiple times

Comment: can you do `phpinfo()` and show the path of `php.ini` file?

Comment: When you run `php -i` from a command prompt Apache is not involved at all.

Comment: it is  /etc/php.ini

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - agreed, but error is same in either case

Comment: try this `date.timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"`, add double quote around.

Comment: Maybe, but you can't use command-line PHP to diagnose web server PHP and viceversa. They are different environments, they some times use different `php.ini` files and, of course, command-lne PHP doesn't care about Apache restarts.

Comment: @DileepKumar - tried it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

change `date.timezone = UTC` 
then run command `sudo service httpd restart`

Comment: Same error. Only last line changed to date.timezone => UTC => UTC

Comment: also run "sudo apache2 restart" command after setting date.timezone=UTC

Answer (score 0):

You could use inside of PHP file:

```
date_default_timezone_set( "YOUR DATE TIME ZONE");
```

for example:

```
date_default_timezone_set( "Europe/Berlin");
```

List of timezones: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

or if you wish to continue using server timezone but want to hide warnings use:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```